# 'skb rides the rocket' in a Xen guest

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I've just set up Ubuntu 13.10 server as a VM on my Ubuntu/Xen server, and I'm getting these weird lines in my guest's syslog.

```
Nov 12 10:26:32 human kernel: [130782.315333] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 19 slots
Nov 12 10:26:32 human kernel: [130782.362405] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 20 slots
Nov 12 10:26:32 human kernel: [130782.408458] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 19 slots
Nov 12 10:26:32 human kernel: [130782.490260] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 20 slots
Nov 12 10:26:32 human kernel: [130782.541931] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 19 slots
Nov 12 10:26:35 human kernel: [130785.226635] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 19 slots
Nov 12 10:26:35 human kernel: [130785.261026] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 21 slots
Nov 12 10:26:35 human kernel: [130785.469306] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 19 slots
Nov 12 10:26:36 human kernel: [130786.552730] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 21 slots
Nov 12 10:26:38 human kernel: [130788.212747] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 20 slots
Nov 12 10:26:38 human kernel: [130788.257544] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 19 slots
Nov 12 10:26:38 human kernel: [130788.903841] xennet: skb rides the rocket: 19 slots
```

Unsure of what they mean, and Google has nothing meaningful.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specific issue? You didn't really ask a question.

Comment: I think his question is what does this strange log message in syslog mean.

Comment: @Richie086 There's no way to know without knowing his circumstances. Is he seeing packet loss? Is he experiencing a problem? Does it happen continuously or is this a one-off event? And so on. (Otherwise, the answer he'll get will likely be incomprehensible -- it indicates the packet sent by netback had more SKB fragments than allowed by the netfront configuration. What that *means* depends on the circumstances.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry, I've been away. It's happening on a regular basis, and I'm experiencing packet loss.

Answer (score 0):

Brendan Gregg recently blogged a nice exploration of [what `skb rides the rocket` means](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-09-11/perf-kernel-line-tracing.html).